# How to code a dynamic solution for the 0/1 Knapsack with a specific number of each item

Tags: algorithm, vba, excel, knapsack-problem

Is it possible to code a dynamic solution to a 1/0 knapsack problem that has a requirement for the number of each item?

For example the knapsack requires:

1 of item_one

2 of item_two

3 of item_three

1 of item_four

1 of item_five

1 of item_six

each item has a weight and there is a max weight of 60000 so in that sense it is just a normal knapsack problem.

beyond that the only difference is Im trying to minimize value instead of maximize.

Here is my brute force code in vba but Im running this over hunderes of items so I need a faster solution. Thanks for the help!

```
 Function knapsacksolver(item_one, item_two, item_three, item_four, item_five, item_six)
    Dim knapsack  As Variant
    ReDim knapsack(1 To 9, 1 To 5) As Variant
    Dim Value As Long
    Dim MinValue As Long
    Dim Cap As Long
    Dim weight As Long

    MinValue = 9999999
    weight = 0
    Cap = 60000

    For i = 1 To UBound(item_one)
        For j = 1 To UBound(item_two)
            For t = 1 To UBound(item_two)
                If j <> t Then
                    For m = 1 To UBound(item_three)
                        For n = 1 To UBound(item_three)
                            If n <> m Then
                                For p = 1 To UBound(item_three)
                                    If n <> p Then
                                        For q = 1 To UBound(item_four)
                                            For r = 1 To UBound(item_five)
                                                For s = 1 To UBound(item_six)
                                                        weight = item_one(i, 3) + item_two(j, 3) + item_two(t, 3) + item_three(m, 3) + item_three(n, 3) + item_three(p, 3) + item_four(q, 3) + item_five(r, 3) + item_six(s, 3)
                                                        Value = item_one(i, 4) + item_two(j, 4) + item_two(t, 4) + item_three(m, 4) + item_three(n, 4) + item_three(p, 4) + item_four(q, 4) + item_five(r, 4) + item_six(s, 4)

                                                        If Value < MinValue And weight < Cap Then
                                                            MinValue = Value
                                                            'adding attribute from each item to array'
                                                            knapsack(1, 1) = item_one(i, 1)
                                                            knapsack(1, 2) = item_one(i, 2)
                                                            knapsack(1, 3) = item_one(i, 3)
                                                            knapsack(1, 4) = item_one(i, 4)
                                                            knapsack(1, 5) = item_one(i, 5)

                                                            knapsack(2, 1) = item_two(j, 1)
                                                            knapsack(2, 2) = item_two(j, 2)
                                                            knapsack(2, 3) = item_two(j, 3)
                                                            knapsack(2, 4) = item_two(j, 4)
                                                            knapsack(2, 5) = item_two(j, 5)

                                                            knapsack(3, 1) = item_two(t, 1)
                                                            knapsack(3, 2) = item_two(t, 2)
                                                            knapsack(3, 3) = item_two(t, 3)
                                                            knapsack(3, 4) = item_two(t, 4)
                                                            knapsack(3, 5) = item_two(t, 5)

                                                            knapsack(4, 1) = item_three(m, 1)
                                                            knapsack(4, 2) = item_three(m, 2)
                                                            knapsack(4, 3) = item_three(m, 3)
                                                            knapsack(4, 4) = item_three(m, 4)
                                                            knapsack(4, 5) = item_three(m, 5)

                                                            knapsack(5, 1) = item_three(n, 1)
                                                            knapsack(5, 2) = item_three(n, 2)
                                                            knapsack(5, 3) = item_three(n, 3)
                                                            knapsack(5, 4) = item_three(n, 4)
                                                            knapsack(5, 5) = item_three(n, 5)

                                                            knapsack(6, 1) = item_three(p, 1)
                                                            knapsack(6, 2) = item_three(p, 2)
                                                            knapsack(6, 3) = item_three(p, 3)
                                                            knapsack(6, 4) = item_three(p, 4)
                                                            knapsack(6, 5) = item_three(p, 5)

                                                            knapsack(7, 1) = item_four(q, 1)
                                                            knapsack(7, 2) = item_four(q, 2)
                                                            knapsack(7, 3) = item_four(q, 3)
                                                            knapsack(7, 4) = item_four(q, 4)
                                                            knapsack(7, 5) = item_four(q, 5)

                                                            knapsack(8, 1) = item_five(r, 1)
                                                            knapsack(8, 2) = item_five(r, 2)
                                                            knapsack(8, 3) = item_five(r, 3)
                                                            knapsack(8, 4) = item_five(r, 4)
                                                            knapsack(8, 5) = item_five(r, 5)

                                                            knapsack(9, 1) = item_six(s, 1)
                                                            knapsack(9, 2) = item_six(s, 2)
                                                            knapsack(9, 3) = item_six(s, 3)
                                                            knapsack(9, 4) = item_six(s, 4)
                                                            knapsack(9, 5) = item_six(s, 5)

                                                        End If
                                                        weight = 0
                                                Next s
                                            Next r
                                        Next q
                                    End If
                                Next p
                            End If
                        Next n
                    Next m
                End If
            Next t
        Next j
    Next i

    knapsacksolver = knapsack
End Function
```

Comment: you are trying to minimize what exactly?

Comment: Value, since ultimately in my dataset each item has a list of unique possible items to choose from (ie item one could be soda, I could ave 200 different sodas to choose from, and each has a weight and value and I have to take exactly one) and in the list the unique items are ranked by preference with 1 being the most preferred which is their value. Thus if I minimize value it will get me a list of the most preferred items that are under the maximum weight.

Comment: Why not use the Solver? It's built-in branch and bound will solve such problems quicker than brute force.